# Unterminated string constant error when outputting script with ClientScriptManager

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using a ClientScriptManager to output script that checks if jQuery is already loaded on the page. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I keep getting an unterminated string error.

Here's the code:

```
private string JQueryCheckScript()
{
    return @"window.jQuery || document.write(""<script src='~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js'></script>"")";
}
```

...

```
var csm = Page.ClientScript;

if (!csm.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("jqueryCheck"))
{
    csm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "jqueryCheck", JQueryCheckScript(), true);
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

It proceeds to render the following script tag, closing the preceding block.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but the fourth parameter in the 
RegisterClientScriptBlock you have the Boolean true.  If that is true  tags are not needed in the string.

Comment: I think the issue is that I'm outputting tags in the DOM in that string. I need that code to be wrapped in a script tag or else it will just be output as plain text.